# Compute weird function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) = e^{x/e} - 2$.

- Explain why the equation $f(x) = 0$ has exactly one root in the interval $[0,e]$
- Find the absolute maximum and minimum values of $f(x)$ in the interval $[0,e]$
- Compute $f^{(n)}(e)$. Simplify your answer as much as possible.

I don't understand the last point at all. What does it even mean?
Thanks

Comment: I am writing an answer, but what is the exponent of $e$? I can't read it.

Comment: The image is very blurry. Can you tell us what $f(x)$ is?

Comment: It is hard to read the original equation. You should enter it in Mathjax. It looks like $f(x)=e^{x/e}-2$. As the question has to do with minima/maxima/derivatives the notation means the $n$th derivative as Nunya says.

Answer (score 4):

It means compute the $n$th derivative of $f$, then evaluate that $n$th derivative at $e$, i.e., substitute $e$ for $x$ in $f^{(n)}(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

It means to compute the $n$-th derivative of the function $f$, i.e. find a general form in terms of $n$.

I assume we have $f(x) = e^{\frac{x}{e}}-2$, but it's too blury to tell.

Then $f^{(1)}(x) = \frac{1}{e}e^{\frac{x}{e}}$

$f^{(2)}(x) = \frac{1}{e^2}e^{\frac{x}{e}}$

Then in general we have $$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{1}{e^n}e^{\frac{x}{e}}$$

$$f^{(n)}(e) = \frac{1}{e^{n}}\cdot e^1=e^{1-n}$$

Comment: +1 I have added parenthesis around the derivative order, so that it is not confused with the power operation :)